# How can I deploy a Grails 3.0.1 war file in Tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat, grails

How can I deploy a `Grails 3.0.1` war file in, a non-embedded version of, Tomcat7? All I'm getting is a blank page or a 404 error.  I can successfully deploy my other war files, so I know it's not a problem with Tomcat.  My versions, and the steps I took are below:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Grails Version: 3.0.1
Groovy Version: 2.4.3
JVM Version: 1.7.0_80
```

I suspect that the problem has something to do with Spring framework or Gradle. I am not very familiar with either of them, but I did notice that 3.0.1 no longer uses a `web.xml` and no longer has a `Config.groovy` file. The site below details how to deploy a Grails project in 3.0.x.

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/deployment.html

1. I ran `grails run-app` and it deployed to `localhost:8080` beautifully with no problems.

I don't want to use the embedded version of Tomcat though. I'd like to deploy it to a different version of Tomcat, and this is where I am running into problems.

2. I changed the scope of my Tomcat dependencies to provided:

   - `provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"`
3. I generated the war file using `grails war`

   - added `website.war` to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`
   - ran `sudo service tomcat7 restart` to restart tomcat
   - checked to see if `website.war` unpacked automatically (it did)
   - checked `localhost:9999/website`

^ This gives me is a blank white page.

4. I deleted `website.war` and it's associated unpacked folder.

   - checked `localhost:9999`
   - it successfully brought me to the default Tomcat screen
   - signed into manager app
   - deployed `website.war` on the manager app
   - it gave me the `ok` status
   - checked `localhost:9999/website`

^ This gives me the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /website, The requested resource is not available.

**Other relevant information:**

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html:

> "Grails 3.0 no longer requires web.xml. Customizations can be done via Spring"

The`BuildConfig.groovy` file has also been changed.

> Old Location: `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`
>   New Location: `build.gradle`
>   Description: Build time configuration is now defined in a Gradle build file

**Other posts I've found:**
(sorry for not providing links, I cannot post more than two links without at least 10 reputation points.)

*grails.org/wiki/Deployment#Tomcat*

- This suggests putting a war in the webapps folder.  I've already tried that and it's not working.

*stackoverflow.com/questions/27557893/grails-app-deploy-in-tomcat-server-using-war-file-fails*

- He is asking a very similar question but he is using a different version of Grails
- The marked solution references `Config.groovy`
- However build time configuration in `Grails 3.0.1` is now in `Build.gradle`
- I don't know if he successfully solved the problem.

*stackoverflow.com/questions/23664421/cant-deploy-grails-war-file-in-tomcat-results-in-404*

- Solution requires change to `Config.groovy`, which is no longer available in `Grails 3.0.1` projects

**EDIT:**

When it unpacks the `website.war` folder the `catalina.out` log file shows this:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)
Jun 07, 2015 3:01:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/website]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:147)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more

Jun 07, 2015 3:01:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/website.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/website]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 07, 2015 3:01:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 07, 2015 3:01:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 26775 ms
```

Then, when I try to load `localhost:9999/website` the `catalina.out` file shows this:

```
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 576 ms
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/website.war
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/website/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/website/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.20.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jun 07, 2015 3:05:07 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
```

Comment: What does the `catalina.out` file for the Tomcat instance show after you've deployed it through the Web UI or through the copying into the `webapps` folder?

Comment: I just added the `catalina.out ` messages after I attempt to deploy `website.war` by copying it into the `webapps` folder.

Answer (score 7):

In an effort to provide a more thorough answer, using the link provided by David Gonzalez Maline, Graeme references a documentation commit in GitHub.

> Note that by default Grails will include an embeddable version of Tomcat inside the WAR file so that it is runnable (see the previous
>   section), this can cause problems if you deploy to a different version
>   of Tomcat. **If you don't intend to use the embedded container then you
>   should change the scope of the Tomcat dependencies to @provided@** prior
>   to deploying to your production container in `build.gradle`:
>
> `provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"`

[Source](https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/68883277b556159372c481822f0325807b9320e6#diff-e9dd31665dc3dc7fd1fc4753432c473aR57) (emphasis mine)

In short, if you leave it at the default `compile` scope, it will include two different versions of Tomcat, Tomcat 7 (which you are deploying to), and Tomcat 8 (which is provided by the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`).

Comment: is it possible to tell it to use 'provided' rather that compile/runtime for certain dependencies depending on whether one wants a tomcat or embedded tomcat war  ?  i.e. not have to change the text by hand before doing a build ?

Comment: @1977 I don't fully understand the question. Why would you want to have both options when creating a build? You could try using a command line variable to control whether things are `compile` or `provided`, but I haven't tried this. It would probably be a good question for the `grails` and `gradle` tags.

Comment: for example if Im doing a build for an external tomcat container I need 'provided' for some dependencies, and if im doing a build for our unit test server I simply want it as 'compile' and in that case I want it to run embedded

Comment: I leave mine as `provided` all the time, and I'm still able to run unit tests. Granted I'm using the `grails test-app unit:` command, rather than creating a build for a unit test server (I haven't heard of that arrangement before, I just have my CI machine run the tests before producing a war). Also, it is typically best if you can create one artifact from the build, so that whatever you use in test is the same as production.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is here:

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-12105

You need to declare the dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat`

as provided in `build.gradle`.

Comment: welcome to SO. It's considered polite to explain, rather than pasting a link to the answer. Please consider editting your answer, so it will be more helpful to visitors.

Comment: Site is no longer available